# Android location search error

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm new to Android and I have this problem I'm trying to make a program that will get my location from the best available provider. After that it gets me the image from the link and I don't know where the error is in the code.

those are the errors i get

at line 102
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement
    - Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete
     IfStatement

at line 142
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

at line 159:
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "setText", = expected after this
     token

at line 162:
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

Thank you in advance

**this is the manifest file:**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.paad.whereami">
  <application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity 
      android:name=".WhereAmI" 
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
  </application>
  <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
  />
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
</manifest>`

**Main.xml:**

'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/myLocationText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"/>
  <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

'

**and this is the code:**

```
package com.paad.whereami;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Timer;

import android.os.SystemClock;





public class WhereAmI extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);    

      Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    updateWithNewLocation(location);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 1, 
                                           locationListener);
  }

  private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
      updateWithNewLocation(null);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                                Bundle extras){ }
  };

  private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
    String latLongString;
    TextView myLocationText;
    myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
    String addressString = "No address found";

    if (location != null) {
      double lat = location.getLatitude();
      double lng = location.getLongitude();
      latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;


      setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(
        "http://blogs.ocweekly.com/navelgazing/boston.jpg");
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
      img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
          Bitmap bitmap = null;

          InputStream in = null;

          try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
          } catch (IOException e1) {
              e1.printStackTrace();
          }
          return bitmap;                
        }
      private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString); 
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                     
          throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
        try{
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect(); 

            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                 
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
              in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                 
            }                     
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
            }
            return in;     
        }  
      }    

      }

    else {
      latLongString = "No location found";
    }
    myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" + 
                            latLongString + "\n" + addressString);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K. Use the preview.

Comment: send your code at success_anil@yahoo.co.in will try to solve it. If you could tell what error you are getting that would be nice

Comment: sorry about that and thank you :)

Comment: @EboMike That's a helpful shortcut.  I'll have to remember that.

Comment: Also, please spell correctly. The clearer the question, the more chances there are that someone will understand the question and care to answer...

Comment: i sent the code to success_anil@yahoo.co and it gave me mailer-domain error

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code, my first guess would be that you try to run it in the emulator and didn't set a position via ddms or telnet "geo fix"?

**Update** Looks like you copy pasted

```
private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
```

and

```
private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
```

at the wrong position. Your curly braces are wrong. At the moment you define a function inside a function.

Comment: i run it on htc my touch im not using an emulator